# Why Manage NuGet packages for solution does not appear install in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package

Why Manage NuGet packages for solution does not appear install in visual studio 2015?.

is there anything I should set in visual studio 2015?

thanks

[Capture-18-10-2022](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4G2FE.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine in my test:
[image]

Maybe you can make the output window smaller or scroll down to see if there is an install button.

Comment: thanks for your answer and maybe my mistake didn't make the size wide